# Return the directory of folder which is the latest based on the date contained in folder name

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I have many folders with date in its name.

If I have three folders named 20150605abcdef, 20161204ghijk, 20180612ikled.

I want to write a VBA code that will return the directory of the folder which has the latest date.

In this case it will return 20180612ikled.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in Excel. Then move that file to first Folder in your structure and just start Macro ReadStructure. It will write in first sheet of your excel all Data from all folders and subfolders in clear tree structure. Then you can use Excel build in tools to find last date like for ex. filter your list.

I translated it from German version for you. So sorry if some parts are still in german Folder=Ordner, Spalte=Column, Zeile=Row, Pfad=Path. for that part i was to lazy

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReadStructure()
 Dim lngZeile As Long
 Dim lngSpalte As Long
 Dim strPFad As String

strPFad = ThisWorkbook.Path
 'Clear all cells form sheet 1
 sheet1.Cells.ClearContents
 sheet1.Range("A1").Value = strPFad

 lngZeile = 2

 Call ReadFilesFolder(strPFad, lngZeile, lngSpalte)

End Sub

Sub ReadFilesFolder(strPFad As String, ByRef lngZeile, ByRef lngSpalte)

 Dim oFSO As Object
 Dim objOrdner As Object
 Dim objUnterordner As Object
 Dim objDatei As Object

 Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objOrdner = oFSO.getfolder(strPFad)

 lngSpalte = lngSpalte + 1
  'Check with loop for folders
  For Each objDatei In objOrdner.Files
    lngZeile = lngZeile + 1
    sheet1.Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value = objDatei.Name
    sheet1.Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Font.Bold = True
  Next objDatei

  For Each objUnterordner In objOrdner.Subfolders
   lngZeile = lngZeile + 1
   sheet1.Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value = objUnterordner.Name & "\"
   sheet1.Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Font.Bold = False
   Call ReadFilesFolder(objUnterordner.Path, lngZeile, lngSpalte)

  Next objUnterordner

  lngSpalte = lngSpalte - 1

  Set oFSO = Nothing

  Exit Sub

 Fehler:
  If Err.Number = 70 Then
  lngZeile = lngZeile + 1
  sheet1.Cells(lngZeile, lngSpalte).Value = "No Acess"
  End If
  lngSpalte = lngSpalte - 1
  Set oFSO = Nothing

  End Sub
```